# Ruby 2.6.1 and Bundler 2.0.1 to Heroku : should I write a Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, bundler

I'm facing errors I can't handle while trying to deploy an app to Heroku (it's my first time).

```
# ERROR when I try to `git push heroku master`
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     Activating bundler (2.0.1) failed:
remote:  !     Could not find 'bundler' (2.0.1) required by your /tmp/build_e569680f858939ef8f1f8ef3e8902eff/Gemfile.lock.
remote:  !     To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
remote:  !     To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.0.1`
remote:  !     Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/tmp/build_e569680f858939ef8f1f8ef3e8902eff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '2.0.1'
```

```
# heroku buildpacks
=== staging-det-music Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

```
# Gemfile.lock
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.1p33

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.1
```

I've tried several solutions, like:

- running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks/36394839#36394839))
- adding the `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` key (same)
- upgrade Ruby to 2.6.3 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935905/could-not-find-bundler-2-0-1-required-by-your-gemfile-lock-while-deploying), can't find 2.6.3 with rbenv nor rvm)

I believe it might be due to [this issue](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues). Am I concerned by this point ?

> 2) When using binstubs to run a command instead of bundle exec the wrong
>   version of Bundler can get activated when using Ruby 2.6.x. This bug
>   is reported to Ruby Core and will be fixed when Ruby 2.6.3 is
>   released.
>
> In the short term, the workaround is to ensure all commands in the
>   Procfile and app.json are prefaced with bundle exec. For example:
>
> `web: bundle exec bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
>
> `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

As a newbie I feel really lost, could anyone help me on this ?

Thanks for your time

**SOLUTION:** found [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/833) removing `BUNDLED WITH` and the following line in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

There are [known issues with Bundler 2 on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues), including this one:

> A Gemfile.lock that specifies bundler 2.0.2 does not work with bundler 2.0.1
>
> If you attempt to deploy an app that uses bundler 2.0.2 onto the Heroku platform with bundler 2.0.1 you may get this error:
>
> ```
> `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
> ```
>
> This is due to a bug in the Rubygems bundler version checking code. To avoid this issue, upgrade your Ruby version. It is fixed in 2.5.5+ and 2.6.3+. If you do not update, your Ruby version then every new release of Bundler 2.x will trigger this issue.

Upgrade Ruby to at least version 2.6.3 locally, update the `ruby` version in your `Gemfile`, `bundle install`, commit the changes, and redeploy.